# Hide element after onclick action

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events

```
<p>
    <a href="#" onclick="showStuff('lol'); return false;">
    <img src='play.png'><br>
    <span id="lol" style="display: none;">
        <iframe src="http://google.com" scrolling="no"></iframe>
   </span>
 </p>
```

With this function, when I click on 'play.png' an iframe will loaded below the image.

What I'm looking for is:

1. How can I "pre-load" the iframe on page loading? So when you click on the image, the content of the iframe is ready.
2. How I can show the iframe only instead the image + iframe? I mean: when I click on the image it should loaded the iframe - so hiding the original image.

Answer (score 0):

you can have something like this:

Have all the content of iframe hidden by adding display:none to body.

On Click perform following function:

```
function showIframeContent(){
   $(document.frames[0]).find('body').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following javascript

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="showStuff('lol'); return false;"><img src='play.png'><br>
<span id="lol" style="display: none;">
    <iframe src="http://google.com" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</span>
</p>

function showStuff(key)
{
    if(document.getElementById(key).style.display == 'none')
    {
        document.getElementById(key).style.display="";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(key).style.display="none";
    }
}
```